# Unable to update a strange HDD firmware

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, updates, firmware

I'm not able to update the firmware on a Seagate ST3500620AS hard drive, neither with the Windows update tool nor the bootable CD (available on this page : http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=207951) These tools are unable to find the hard drive (it displays scanning SATA disk... 0 disks detected).

But this hard drive is detected by the BIOS and by Hirens Boot CD.

The reason I want to update the hard drive firmware is because it doesn't work properly. I'm unable to mount it in Windows 7, in Hiren Boot CD mini-XP it works sometime but I'm not able to make a backup of this HDD because I'm always getting errors when I'm trying to do so.

Seatools is unable to detect this hard drive.

Comment: IS it even possible to update a harddisk firmware?

Comment: In some cases yes. Often with enterprise drives vendors suggest all in an array be same firmware

Comment: If you cannot mount it in windows then the firmware update is likely to fail! Send it to Seagate (usually they have 3 year warranty) - let them sort it out.. If there is data on there that you need.. its most likely gone... but you can spend a few hundred dollar to get it recovered though.. tough luck mate. You should have backed up.

Answer (score 2):

This may indicate an issue with the drive.  Have you used the Seagate diagnostic tool to fully test the drive?  [Seatools](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=seatools-win&vgnextoid=552bd20cacdec010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD) can be downloaded here.